# Multi Language Support in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I need to implement Multiple Languages(e.g. 5 languages).

My app is also using Web-Service & also save some data in User defaults.

User can able to change the language any time during the app.

**Doubts:**

1) How can I check condition for saved user-Defaults Data?

2) How to communicate with Web-Service for Get/Post Data?

**My try**

I search a lot on google but all solution are just shows for Labels through Separate nib file & Key-Value compliant.

**Please Help me to solve this.**

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to search for `NSLocalizedString()`?

Comment: Thanks for Your Reply! Yes,I tried but all search just shows me static  Localized String not Dynamic.

Comment: @user2893370 what do you mean by saying `Dynamic` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your language localize file into Localizable.strings.

and also add all file into localization filed on project Info option...